# Swiftでのカスタムキーボードについて

Tags: ios, swift2

現在swiftでiOS向けのカスタムキーボードを作っています。ローマ字を入力することは出来るようになったのですが、iOS標準キーボードのようなローマ字入力での日本語変換方法がみあたりません。参考になる記事等がありましたらご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

残念ながら、日本語変換のAPIはありませんので、自分でその仕組みを実装する必要があります。

簡単な方法として、Google日本語入力のAPIなど日本語変換のWeb APIを使用する方法があります。この場合は日本語変換にネットワークアクセスが必要になります。

https://www.google.co.jp/ime/cgiapi.html

あまり簡単ではない方法としてGoogle日本語入力のオープンソース版やをiOS用にビルドする、という方法もあります。

（例）
https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/Mozc-for-iOS